# How to prevent page load on form submission

Tags: plugins, php, functions, forms

I have finally managed to get my plugin working. However, upon submission  the whole page reloads along with my output above the form. How can I avoid my page to completely reload and not to display the form once it is submitted?

```
<?php    
function installer(){
    include('installer.php');
}
register_activation_hook( __file__, 'installer' ); //executes installer php when installing plugin to create new database

add_action('admin_menu','result_menu'); //wordpress admin menu creation

function result_menu()
{
    add_menu_page('Result','Result','administrator','xenon-result');
    add_submenu_page( 'xenon-result', 'Manage Marks', ' Manage Marks', 'administrator', 'Manage-Xenon-Marks', 'Xenon_Marks' );
}

function Xenon_Marks() //function to add marks addition form in admin view
{
    include('new/result-add-marks.php');
}

function html_form_code() 
{
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Student Information</legend>';
echo 'Roll Number: <input type="number" min="170001" max="171000" name="rollNumber"><br>';
echo '<input type="submit">';
echo '<input type ="reset">';
echo '</form>';
}

function result_display(){
global $wpdb;
$student_id = $_POST['rollNumber'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_xenonresult` WHERE `student_id` = $student_id";
$result = $wpdb->get_row($query);
echo $result->student_name;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   result_display();
}

function display_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    result_display();
    html_form_code();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'xenon_result_display', 'display_shortcode' );
// Enable shortcodes in text widgets
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are using AJAX for sending/fetching data, you must tolerate reloading a whole page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unaware about the AJAX, how do I know? Also it would be great if you could direct me how to do it using Ajax so that I may read and try.

Comment: [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) represents group of techniques of exchanging data between client web browser and server without refreshing whole page. You can seamlessly pull data from server and present it in some DIV container, for example. Javascript is used to perform AJAX calls, data is usually exchanged in XML format, and HTML is used to present data to user.

Answer (score -1):

Like losmi said, you need to use AJAX to avoid page reloads.  If you're using jQuery you should do something like this:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  var data = $(this).serialize());
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: /path/to/admin-ajax.php,
    data: data,
    action: something_descriptive
  })
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT:  Mark makes a fair point.  In wordpress your AJAX calls should be handled by wordpress.  You do this by adding a function to the ajax handler filters using the naming style below

```
add_filter('wp_ajax_something_descriptive', 'your_ajax_handler');
add_filter('wp_ajax_nopriv_something_descriptive', 'your_ajax_handler');
function your_ajax_handler() {
    /*do your form handling here, anything passed in the data object will be 
    available as a $_POST variable.  TO return content to the AJAX call echo it out.  
    Be sure to die() at the end of the function*/
}
```

The action that you pass in the AJAX call becomes part of the filter name `wp_ajax_ACTION` and logged in users and `wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION` for not logged in users.  Int he wild please be more specific than I was in your jQuery targeting, always check to make sure things exist before manipulating them, and make your function and action names logical.

Comment: Learn more about AJAX from places like [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery) or [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59)

Comment: downvoted as in the context of wordpress it is a very partial answer